# replace a string with another string (why does the second one with 'new_string = a_sub_string" comes out "l"?)

Tags: python

[image]

what's the differences between these two? why does the second one with 'new_string = a_sub_string" comes out "l"?

Comment: Please add the text code to the question. Code in images is hard to troubleshoot

Comment: `x+=y` is the same as saying `x=x+y`. That is the difference in this code

Comment: `new_string += a_sub_string` vs `new_string = a_sub_string`.  This question should be closed as a typo issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because every time the loop gets executed, `new_string` is assigned the current value of `a_sub_string`, and the in the last iteration of the loop, `a_sub_string = l` i.e the last character in string `a`.
I hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The first code **appends**.

The second code **reassigns** to the same variable, therefor only collecting the value that was processed at the very last.